# Firebase Firestore collection could not retrieve - react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

**Context:** I have a list of doctors on Firebase Firestore and I want to retrieve data related to them.

**Problem:** App is behaving like collection is empty but it currently contains three doctors. I want to retrieve data in list of objects so I can access them in app. Also, if you have any other idea of retrieving the data let me know, since I haven't found any that works for me.

Here is the problematic part of code:

```
componentDidMount(){

firebase.firestore().collection('doctors')
            .get()
            .then((querySnapshot
                ) => {
                querySnapshot.forEach(snapshot  => {
                
                const doctors = []
                snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data()
                    data.id = doc.id;
                    doctors.push(data)
                                       
                })
                this.setState({doctors :doctors})
            })})
        
    }
```

Here is how my Firebase looks like:

[image: firestore]

Answer (score 0):

I found this snippet which I believe it's your exact use case:

```
// retrieve a collection
db.collection('documents')
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    const documents = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
    // do something with documents
  })
```

You may find this example, and others [here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/typescript/firestore+get+all+documents+in+collection). Under each snippet, you can find the original source in case you want more context for each snippet.